# Is It Possible For All Insurers To Leave the State?

Tags: united-states, affordable-care-act

[UnitedHealth is leaving a few Georgia, Arkansas and Michigan](http://www.zerohedge.com/news/2016-04-18/obamacare-exodus-accelerates-after-georgia-and-arkansas-biggest-health-insurer-exits) - hitting home in our case, and what happens if its former competitors in those states do?  Does ACA have an alternative route for people's health insurance outside of what's available through employment?

Comment: If you include homeowner's insurance, Insurance companies threaten to do this every now and again when the claims get too high, or they are in a tuffle with the state regulators.

Answer (score 4):

Possible? Sure. Likely? Not a chance; there's to much money to be made from selling insurance policies, and the more open the market becomes, the more likely someone else will want to move in to capture some of those customers.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. The insurance companies are complaining that they are losing money in some states.

They are businesses. They have investors.

Will they all pull out of the ACA market in a state? There is no way to know.

Will they complain every time they submit higher rates and they get cut back by the state insurance commissioners? Yes.

The big question is: when will the healthy people without insurance purchase it? When they enter the market the ACA products will start to become profitable.

Comment: I'm a little confused - what other options are available to the healthy?  Are you suggesting that healthy people are just not signing up for health care at all?